# MYSQL DateTime Query to get values on the particular date

Tags: mysql

Let the table contains the fields id,amount,createdDate where createdDate is in timeStamp

```
**1.**em.createNamedQuery("select Sum(t.amount) from tablename t
 WHERE cast(t.createdDate as date) = :createdDate")**
```

Let the createdDate be '2012-3-23'
Now the result would be the sum of all the amount on the particular date('2012-3-23') from time 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 .

The another Way is by

```
 **2.em.createNamedQuery("select Sum(t.amount) from tablename t
WHERE t.createdDate between :fromDate and :todate")**
```

The values of fromDate is'2012-3-23 0:0:0' and todate as'2012-3-23 23:59:59'

Now the result would be the sum of all the amount on the particular date('2012-3-23') from time 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 .

The above two queries work successful.

**Is there any other way to get the result without using 
1.cast in the query 
2.Giving the fromdate and todate with the specified time values as mentioned above.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DATE() function:

```
select DATE(createdDate), SUM(t.amount) from tableName t
where DATE(createdDate) =:createdDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATE` function.

```
SELECT SUM(t.amount) FROM tablename t WHERE DATE(createdDate) = :createdDate
```